# Why is sample() different in SparkR to R?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sample

I've some experience in R and am learning Spark 1.6.1 by first exploring the implementation of R in Spark.

I noticed that the syntax for the R sample() command is different in Spark:

base::R: `sample(x, size, replace)`

Spark R: `sample(DataFrame, withReplacement, fraction)`

`base::sample(x, size, replace)` still works, but is masked by the Spark R version.

Does anyone know why this is, when most commands are identical between the two?

Are there use cases that I should use one versus the other?

Has anyone found an authoritative list of differences between Spark R and base:: R?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many package which mask base function and change their behavior. I think you should read documentation of `base::sample` and `SparkR::sample` for answers to some of your questions. When building your solution around it, just use `importFrom` in your NAMESPACE file, and use the one you need.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @jangoreck.  I think maybe you missed the point of the question.  I know that masking is common behavior, and I know how to explicitly choose the masked version.  The normal use of masking is to provide a similarly named function for a very different context.  In this case, both were remarkably similar.  Input a data frame, take a subset of the rows by random sample, output a data frame.  There did not seem to be a point to the new version of the function with marginally different parameters presented in a different sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a SparkR dataframe, you'll need to use the SparkR api for sampling. If you have a R dataframe, you'll need to use the base::R sampling function call. SparkR is not R and the function calls are not identical.

The issue you are having is one of [masking](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#r-function-name-conflicts).

Comment: Thank you @David.  This is very helpful ... with the lack of strong documentation and educational materials on the interaction of R and SparkR, I find it's never entirely clear whether I have an R data frame or a Spark data frame.  Good to know that we have a sample function for each type of df ... now I just need to work out a clear way of establishing which I have in any given variable name!

Comment: btw @David, your answer will be upvoted once my kudos increases by 1

Answer (score 0):

To address the second part of the question, for the benefit of others who follow, I found that the Spark documentation does in fact list the R functions that are masked:
[R Function Name Conflicts](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#r-function-name-conflicts)